# Adding 1 to an input int vector and returning the answer in vector again

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> plusOne(vector<int>& digits) {
        vector<int>result;
        unsigned long long c =0,answer;
        for (int i=0; i<digits.size(); i++){
            c = pow(10, i)*(digits[digits.size()-1-i]) + c;
            //cout<<"loop"<<endl;
        }
        answer = c+1;
        while (answer){
            result.insert(result.begin(),answer%10);
            answer = answer/10;
        }

        return result;
    }
};
```

I get an error for long vectors.
Ex: for testcase , [6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3]
My code is giving output as [6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,**4,0,9]**
last three digits are wrong

Comment: `pow(10, i)` -- This is a floating point function, thus is susceptible to round-off issues..

Comment: `pow` returns a `double`, not an integer. Rounding errors are normal when dealing with floating point numbers. You need to think of a different approach.

Comment: Agree with @Yksisarvinen -- The problem you're trying to solve more than likely can be solved with pure, simple integers, and no need whatsoever for floating point functions or even a power function (even if the power function worked correctly)

Comment: Storing the number created from the digits in the vector doesn't sound like the right solution. What if the vector has one thousand digits or something? You definitely can't store that in an `unsigned long long`.

Comment: You're getting overflow on your intermediate value `c`. I think that idea is that you add one **without** using C++ arithmetic. Do the addition in the vectors directly, not by using C++ arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

If someone asked you to add one to a large number, would you use the `pow` function? Obviously not. This is how you should write the function

```
vector<int> plusOne(const vector<int>& digits) {
    vector<int> result = digits;
    int carry = 1;
    int i = digits.size() - 1;
    while (i > 0 && carry) {
        ++result[i];
        if (result[i] < 10)
            carry = 0;
        else
            result[i] = 0;
        --i;
    }
    if (carry)
        result.insert(result.begin(), 1); // overflow, e.g. 9999 => 10000
    return result;
}
```

Untested code.

Comment: Appreciate your help.But curious as to why does it fail for large numbers?

Comment: Either because of the overflow when calculating `c`, or because of rounding errors in converting the `double` returned from `pow` to an integer. Thinking about it, it's probably the latter.